# amazon ec2 apache crash

Tags: apache, crash, amazon-ec2

my apache server on amazon ec2 crashes for some reason,

```
[Tue Jun 18 09:28:26.008659 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4806] AH00052: child pid 6226 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jun 18 09:28:26.008735 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4806] AH00052: child pid 6227 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jun 18 09:28:26.008752 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4806] AH00052: child pid 6228 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jun 18 09:28:28.017033 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4806] AH00052: child pid 6151 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jun 18 09:28:46.035989 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4806] AH00052: child pid 6120 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Jun 18 09:28:47.388781 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4806] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jun 18 09:28:51.712473 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6276] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Jun 18 09:28:51.891491 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6277] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Jun 18 09:28:51.891584 2013] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 6277] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Jun 18 09:28:51.943536 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6277] AH00163: Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

what is causing that and what can i do ?

Comment: Last line in that log indicates it started normally and resumed operation. How do you know it crashed? Can you get to the site? can you see Apache in "ps aux "

Comment: i know it crashed because that what cause me to look at the error log , and this is not the first time. the last line is there probably because i restarted it. how can i find out what was the reason for the crash ?

Comment: In the logs, look for "errors & notices" and for now ignore "warnings. Also, see if anything is running on port 80 "netstat -tulpn | grep 80"

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, it looks like this the problem:

```
"Apache exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" [This is what you need to google]
```

Check if you have enough resources(Memory(free -m) and disk-space). 
Then, if still stuck, you may want create dump as explained below and dig into that dump

Section: Debugging intermittent crashes
http://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html

Comment: after a long search i have found a recommendation to use gdb to debug httpd , problem is when i use "gdb /opt/bitnami/apache2" i get "/opt/bitnami/apache2: No such file or directory" even though it exists .... anyone ?

Comment: Not familiar with gdb? are you using Redmine for bitnami?.